# Find set with smallest number of elements from a list of sets

Tags: python-3.x, nested

I have a list of sets -

`inconsistent_case = [{0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7}, {4, 5}]`

I want -

`{4, 5}` (set with smallest number of elements)

My code -

```
length = float("inf")
small = {}
for x in inconsistent_case:
    if len(x) < length:
        length = len(x)
        small = x
print(small)
```

Which gives me -

`{4, 5}`

Is there any fastest and/or easiest way to do this?

Comment: Thanks @Patrick Haugh, marked it as duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, specify the key for `min`:

```
>>> inconsistent_case = [{0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7}, {4, 5}]
>>> min(inconsistent_case, key=len)
{4, 5}
```

If multiple items are minimal, the function returns the first one encountered.

Comment: Thanks @wim that works perfectly fine!